# Change Guest Account Picture in Windows 8.1?

Tags: user-accounts, windows-8.1

Is there a way to change the Windows 8.1 Guest Account Picture and how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this answer (from http://d4rkcell.com/archives/1410) :

> Some guides I read online talk about a folder at
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Default Account Pictures. This directory
>   didn’t exist on my version of Windows 8.1 enterprise so use the folder
>   in step 4 below instead.
>
> 1. Create your image in paint.net as 448 x 448 save it as a BMP file and
>      again as a PNG file, name the files user.bmp and user.png.
> 2. Resize the image to 200×200 and save as User-200.png
> 3. Resize the image to 40×40 and save as user-40.png
> 4. Copy these files to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account Pictures
> 5. If you want to manage the guest account pictures replace guest.png and
>      guest.bmp with the 448 x 448 copies of your image named appropriately.
> 6. Delete any .dat files in the folder and restart.
>
> The default is now this image. Handy if you want a corporate logo. The
>   various sizes make this image visible in various places such as the
>   top right corner (smaller image), the login screen etc.

Comment: this could also be applied offline to a mounted install.wim image.